# C low level read write functions 64-bit equivalent?

Tags: c

I have some code that uses the low level i/o `read` and `write` system calls, as described on page 170  of the C programming language book Kernighan and Ritchie.
The function prototypes are this

```
int n_read = read  ( int fd, char *buf, int n )
int n_read = write ( int fd, char *buf, int n )
```

now the two .c file that uses these `read` and `write` are called by a larger fortran based program to read and write lots of data.

the C code is simply this, with no `#include` of any kind, having the underscore after the function name and passing by reference:

```
int read_ ( int *descriptor, char *buffer, int *nbyte )
{
   return ( read( *descriptor, buffer, *nbyte ) );
}

int write_ ( int *descriptor, char *buffer, int *nbyte )
{
   return ( write( *descriptor, buffer, *nbyte ) );
}
```

and the larger fortran based program will do something like this

```
INTEGER nbyte
COMPLEX*16 matrix(*)
INTEGER READ, WRITE
EXTERNAL READ, WRITE

status = READ( fd, matrix, nbyte )
if ( status .eq. -1 ) then
   CALL ERROR('C call read failure')
   stop
endif
```

As you may have already guessed, this works fine for **nbyte** values less than 2^31.  I have a need to read more than 2 GB of data, so i need **nbyte** to be a **long integer** and **INTEGER*8** in fortran.

Is there an equivalent read64 and write64,  like there is an lseek64 provided by unistd.h and features.h ?

what is the best way to recode this?
should i use fread and fwrite ?
is the `int fd` from the low level `write` the same as `FILE *stream` from `fread()` ?

my requirement is being able to pass a long integer of 8 bytes to allow for values up to 100 to 500 gigabytes or an integer having 12 digits, which is all for the value of **nbyte**

Am i gaining anything or losing out by currently using `read` and `write` which is identified as a **"system call"** ?  What does this mean?

Comment: What about successive reads in small chunks until all is read?

Comment: K&R C is not something you should learn nowadays, except if you are curious for historic reasons. Lots of stuff there is frowned upon, outdated or plain wrong nowadays. For example, if you had just RTFM for the `read()` function, you would have found the declaration that Leandros gave you and probably solved your problem yourself.

Comment: That would at best be an ugly workaround, @WeatherVane. It is still something to keep in mind if the Fortran side can't interface with C code.

Comment: For up-to-date information on library functions, open a terminal window, and  use the `man` command. For example, `man 2 read` tells you all about the `read` function. The number 2 indicates the section in the manual. Section 1 is mostly shell commands. Sections 2 and 3 have the C library functions.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** You can't, at least not on Linux. `read` will never transfer more than what a 32-bit integer can hold.

From the manpages of Linux on `read`:

> On Linux, read() (and similar system calls) will transfer at most
>          0x7ffff000 (2,147,479,552) bytes, returning the number of bytes
>          actually transferred.  (This is true on both 32-bit and 64-bit
>          systems.)

This is not a contraint of POSIX, it's allowed by POSIX, but in the end it's implementation defined how `read` behaves. As [Andrew Hanle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4756299/andrew-henle) reports, reading a 32GB file works just fine on Solaris. In this case, my old answer is still valid.

**Old Answer:**

`read` can work with 64-bit files just fine. It's defined in `<unistd.h>` as the following:-

```
ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
```

You would have to adjust your routines to work with `size_t` instead of `int`, to properly support big files.

You should check `SSIZE_MAX` (the maximum value supported for `count`), before using `read` with a big file, and abort if it's to small (or split into smaller chunks). `SSIZE_MAX` is an implementation defined value.

Comment: How do you know that `size_t` is big enough to handle 64-bit numbers?  It is allowed to have a maximum representable value as small as 65534.

Comment: @JohnBollinger He's using the POSIX API, not stdio. Doesn't POSIX require `size_t` to be large enough for the maximum file size?

Comment: @Barmar, POSIX and C both allow `SIZE_MAX` to be as small as 65534.  See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdint.h.html

Comment: Ahh, I see. POSIX has `off_t` for file offsets, but a single `read()` may still be limited to `size_t`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger If you can't assume that `size_t` is 64 bits on a 64-bit system, then `size_t` is rather useless, isn't it? (Perhaps that was your point.) In any case, the OP could check the `sizeof(size_t)` at runtime, and abort if it's not 8.

Comment: @user3386109, why would that make it useless?  It perhaps should make you think more carefully about what types you use for what purpose, but `size_t`, by definition, serves those purposes for which it is designated.  Instead of assuming it is a wide type, you should consider using a specified-width type such as `uint64_t`, or  a maximum-width type such as `uintmax_t`, where you want a wide type.

Comment: @user3386109 Checking if `SSIZE_MAX` is big enough is the better solution. On 64-bit linux `SSIZE_MAX` is normally defined to be `LONG_MAX`. `read` doesn't have to support the whole range of `size_t` (and generally doesn't, since `size_t` is unsigned)

Comment: @Leandros, no, checking the width of `size_t` is still insufficient.  Even if `size_t` is 64 bits wide, that doesn't mean that `read()` or `write()` will *ever* transfer any given number of bytes in one call.  In fact, some widely-used implementations are limited to no more than can be represented by an `int`, despite `ssize_t` having a greater range.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I said checking `size_t` is not enough ... you have to check `SSIZE_MAX`, and the return value of `read()`. Also, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

As @Leandros observed, POSIX-conforming implementations of `read()` and `write()` accept byte counts of type `size_t`, and return byte counts of type `ssize_t`.  These are probably the definitions that actually apply to you, as the `read()` and `write()` functions are not specified by the C standard.  That's a distinction without much difference, however, because `size_t` is not required to be wider than `int` -- in fact, it can be narrower.

You anyway have a bigger problem.  The Fortran code seems to assume that the C functions it is calling will read / write the full specified number of bytes or else fail, but POSIX `read()` and `write()` are not guaranteed to do that when they succeed.  Indeed, there was a question around here the other day that hinged on the fact that these functions did not transfer more bytes at a time than can be represented by a signed, 32-bit integer, even on a 64-bit system with 64-bit `[s]size_t`.

You can kill both of these birds with one stone by implementing the `read_()` and `write_()` functions to *loop*, performing successive calls to the underlying `read()` or `write()` function, until the full number of specified bytes is transferred or an error occurs.

Comment: You have to. `read` does not support reading more than 0x7ffff000  bytes.

Comment: @Leandros, whereas that is true of some implementations, which is already covered in my answer, POSIX does not require it to be true of all implementations.  But yes, that makes it a very good idea to loop.

Comment: Correct. You can't generally answer it, in a non implementation defined manner. While it's not possible on Linux, some other POSIX compliant platforms might support it. (thinking about Darwin here)

Comment: Neither Darwin nor any BSD man page mention any limitation, except the size of `size_t`.

Comment: @Leandros *You have to. read does not support reading more than 0x7ffff000 bytes.*  [Not technically true](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pread.html):  *If the value of `nbyte` is greater than `{SSIZE_MAX}`, the result is implementation-defined.* `SSIZE_MAX` on a 64-bit system is quite a bit larger than `0x7ffff000`.    I just ran a quick test on Solaris 11 and successfully read 32GB in one read operation and only couldn't read larger because a 64GB allocation failed. Good code will handle short reads, though, no matter how large the requested number of bytes may be.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Technically very true, on Linux. As stated in my answer. As John stated, it's not true for every POSIX implementation.

Comment: @Leandros Well, your comment that I was responding to didn't qualify your original *"`read` does not support reading more than 0x7ffff000 bytes"*.  It's irrelevant, though, because code [**must** handle short reads anyway](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pread.html): *If a `read()` is interrupted by a signal after it has successfully read some data, it shall return the number of bytes read.*